# Is there a way to process PDF files in Blob Storage without downloading them locally using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

**Summarize the problem:**

I am trying to process multiple PDFs to an OCR program written in Python. During local development, PDFs are located in a local directory where can be processed but I wasn't able to figure it out a path-like filesystem in Blob Storage. Technically speaking, I know there is no such filesystem in Blob but I need such path to be passed in OCR program. Any ways we can achieve this?

**What I've tried:**

Currently I have the code below to connect to container and blobs in `azure.py`:

```
import os
import glob
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, PublicAccess

# list input PDF files 
def ls_files(client, path, recursive=False):
    if not path == '' and not path.endswith('/'):
        path += '/'

    blob_list = client.list_blobs(name_starts_with=path)
    files = []
    for blob in blob_list:
        relative_path = os.path.relpath(blob.name, path) # blob.name is the name of blobs in containers
        if recursive or not '/' in relative_path:
            files.append(relative_path)
            files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.pdf')] # look for PDF files 
    return files

# connection string to the storage account
connect_str = '<connection string>'
# same container but different folders for inputs and outputs 
container_name = 'ocr'

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

input_files = ls_files(client, '', recursive=True) # This is the input PDF files 

for files in input_files:
    ############################
    # kick off OCR program here#
    ############################ 
    print('Processing ...', files, '\n')
```

In `main.py` file:

```
import azure as az 

input_directory = az.input_files # input_directory was like '/Users/xyz/path/to/local/dir'

# do regular OCR processing next
```

After executing the script, Python is unable to recognize file or path in Blob Storage. Is there a way that we can achieve goal here? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

I came across [this sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/4306898850dd21617644fc537a57d025e833db74/samples/blob/append_blob_usage.py#L314) but I'm afraid that is for older version of Python SDK not for V12. Also been looking at official [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples) but to no avail.

**EDIT 2:**

Ok. Opened a ticket [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/72629/is-it-possible-to-process-pdf-files-with-full-path.html) to seek out help from MSFT team and will update here once I know more. The workarounds are 1) download files as memory streams or 2) create a temp file in Python to serve as a placeholder. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: This OCR tool is somewhat proprietary or we can have a look at the API?

Comment: I am afraid that's proprietary :( @MarekPiotrowski

Comment: So, at least, is it a separate process/application or just another python module with full access to sources?

Comment: modules. basically `main.py` does everything. `azure.py` here just to fetch that path if any exists in blob storage. @MarekPiotrowski

Comment: So I'd try to check the place where OCR receives a the binary ie after the file is loaded/dedoded from mass storage to the memory. Then I'd try to 'convert' Azure blob (which is already in memory, if it's even possible to load it to memory and not download from Azure) to similar form which OCR accepts.

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski thanks for your input. I've decided to give a try to download it as memory streams and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Azure Storage BLOB you can use Azure Storage File Shares, also you can use Azure Cognitive Services Computer Vision API for OCR as well
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text

Comment: Ah I was just looking at docs for azure storage file shares yesterday and would like to give a try today. As for API for OCR, we would want to stay with what we currently have